# What happens when "recommend deletion" and "delete" are mixed in LQP review?

Tags: support, review, low-quality-posts, vote-to-delete, trusted-user

In Low Quality Posts review, what happens when <20k users chose "recommend deletion", and 20k users chose "delete" for the same review? For example, if a post had 3 "recommend deletion" reviews and 2 "delete" reviews, would it be deleted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, based on experience only, it's a "first one wins" case, meaning that when one of the following happens, the review is completed and post is deleted:

- Three users with 20k rep choose "Delete".
- Six users with less than 20k rep choose "Recommend Deletion".

The order of the review actions doesn't matter.

Based on that, when a post has 3 "Recommend Deletion" and 2 "Delete" reviews, nothing happens. If a third user with 20k rep choose "Delete", it will be deleted, or if three more <20k rep users choose "Recommend Deletion".

Note: above applies only for answers with negative score. Answers with positive score can't be deleted from review, just send mod flag when review is completed.

Comment: Feature request: make this sane and count "Recommend Deletion" as .5 of a "Delete" vote, then delete when the sum reaches 3.

Comment: @JoshCaswell interesting idea! :-)